# Trying Sort_Index on a index having weeks as w1, w2, and so on, and it's not working?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe looks something like this-

```
                 User1              User2              User3           User4
w1                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w10                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w11                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w12                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w13                 0                 0                 1                 1   
w14                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w15                 0                 1                 0                 0   
w16                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w17                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w18                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w19                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w2                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w20                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w21                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w22                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w23                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w24                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w25                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w26                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w27                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w28                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w29                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w3                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w30                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w31                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w32                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w33                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w34                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w35                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w36                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w37                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w38                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w39                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w4                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w40                 1                 0                 0                 0   
w41                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w42                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w43                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w44                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w45                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w46                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w47                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w48                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w49                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w5                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w50                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w51                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w52                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w53                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w54                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w55                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w56                 0                 0                 0                 0   
w6                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w7                  0                 0                 0                 0   
w8                  0                 0                 0                 0
```

Now, I'm trying to sort this df by index, and the sort index command that I am using-

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True,axis=0)
```

is not working? Any idea why it's so? I even tried adding Ascending=True as an argument, it still doesn't work.

Desired output would be the entire dataframe sorted by weeks-

```
w1

w2

w3
```

and so on..

Comment: Try `df.sort_index(axis=0,inplace=True)`

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @bigbounty tried it, doesn't work. I've made some edits to illustrate the issue better, check them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update using pandas 1.1.0+ [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys) now has key paramter:

```
df.sort_index(key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)').squeeze().astype(int))
```

---

IIUC, you want to do a numerical sort on this string type dataframe index?

Try:

```
idx = df.index.str.extract('(\d+)').squeeze().astype(int).sort_values().index
df.iloc[idx]
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us try `natsort` : Notice you should install this tool box first

```
from natsort import index_natsorted
df=df.iloc[index_natsorted(df.index)]
```